# Access Subquery

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, subquery

I've been struggling with a query problem for a few days and browsed for answers and think that I may just be unable to apply the logic found because I'm not great at SQL. I have two tables, [0100] and [Product] and need to calculate the variance between Actual and Forecast for each Category. I have tried a number of subqueries but cannot get them to work so am back to this:

```
SELECT
    Product.Description,
    Sum([0100].Actual) AS Actual,
    Sum([0100].Forecast) AS Forecast,
    Sum(IIf([0100]![Forecast]=0,
            IIf([0100]![Actual]=0,
                0,
                IIf([0100]![Actual]>0,9.99,-9.99)
            ),
            ([0100]![Actual]-[0100]![Forecast])/[0100]![Forecast]
        )
    ) AS Variance
FROM
    0100
    INNER JOIN Product ON [0100].Category = Product.ID
GROUP BY
    Product.Description;
```

Once I have the Variance Column working, I will remove Actual and Forecast Columns but I am unable to get the Variance Column to work correctly and I suspect it is because I need a subquery. Having tried many times, I am at a loss as to how to proceed.I have it working in Excel as per the following snapshot with the formula `=IF(AND(B2=0,C2=0),0,IF(C2=0,IF(B2>0,9.99,-9.99),(B2-C2)/C2))`

```
**Column A                             B           C          Formula
Account Group                     Actual      Forecast     Variance**
Admin & Management staff costs    -8256.61    -8256.61           0%
Bank interest                       0                0           0%
Care staff 4 weekly paid             268           268           0%
Care staff travel   -70 -70 0%
Contracts - health & soc services -748317.97   -788317.97       -5%
Donations & fundraising             -9665.69     -9465.69        2%
Fundraising & promotion              4695.68      4695.68        0%
Grants                                -28687       -39687      -28%
```

Could anyone provide help in getting the Variance query right so it returns the same result as the Excel formula? I have a sample database with just the product table and the `0100` table with the records returning the Excel results provided and will see if I can attach/provide a link.

Many Thanks,

Simon

Comment: Please show the actual and expected results and sample tables in the question. The question (without attachments) should include all the necessary information to provide an answer.

Comment: Always post error message or undesired results you receive as *but cannot get them to work* is not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Excel's

```
=IF(AND(B2=0,C2=0),0,IF(C2=0,IF(B2>0,9.99,-9.99),(B2-C2)/C2))
```

equivalent in Access is:

```
IIf([0100]![Actual] = 0 And [0100]![Forecast] = 0,
    0,
    IIf([0100]![Forecast] = 0,
        IIf([0100]![Actual] > 0, 9.99, -9.99),
        ([0100]![Actual]-[0100]![Forecast]) / [0100]![Forecast]
    )
)
```

If the values can be `Null` (i.e., if you have empty fields) test `Nz(x) = 0` instead of just `x = 0`.

```
IIf(Nz([0100]![Actual]) = 0 And Nz([0100]![Forecast]) = 0,
    0,
    IIf(Nz([0100]![Forecast]) = 0,
        IIf(Nz([0100]![Actual]) > 0, 9.99, -9.99),
        (Nz([0100]![Actual])-Nz([0100]![Forecast])) / Nz([0100]![Forecast])
    )
)
```

The function `IIf(condition, IfExpression, ElseExpression)` returns either `IfExpression` or `ElseExpression` but it always evaluates both expressions. Therefore, it is necessary to apply the `Nz()` function even in the cases where the value is tested to be <> 0. `Nz()` converts `Null` to `Empty` and `Empty` is the default value for a type. It is `0` for numeric types and the empty string for strings etc.